# Can you tell PHP to send headers (like 500) when an error occurs?

Tags: php, error-handling

In my current project I'm querying PHP with normal HTTP-request but also via AJAX where I sometimes return JSON-formatted data and sometimes normal text. When an error occurs, in  a normal request, you see the error-message and can do something about it. With AJAX-requests on the other hand you cannot be sure if you get an error or the data you want because it isn't displayed directly — you just run into troubles because your app won't work any more.

So I thought about an error-handling-system. My best idea is to send a 500 "Internal Server Error" header if an error occurs, so in my JS, when I send an AJAX-Request, I can simply check for errors that way and handle it.

Unfortunately PHP doesn't send that kind of header (like when you have a parse-error, or something in your code goes wrong) natively.

Can you:

a) Tell PHP to send headers like 500 if an error occurs? Or
b) Use set_error_handler to send a 500-header and then call PHP regular error handling? Or
c) Can you, in any other way send error headers when a PHP error occurs?

Comment: `try` some code, `catch` errors then use `header()` to send http response codes.

Comment: @Arvin: Exceptions do not catch parse errors.

Comment: @Toma Why would you upload and use PHP files with syntax errors?

Comment: Well, I do also run into errors locally while developing and testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i prefer using Exceptions for handling errors. First, you need to install error-to-exception error handler (http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php, example 1), then wrap your main application code in a try-catch block and send appropriate headers in the catch part. For example:

```
try {
    $myApplication->run();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   // log or otherwise register the error
   header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}
```

unfortunately, this doesn't work with so-called "Fatal errors", to handle these you have to use stupid tricks like this

```
ob_start();

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    $p = ob_get_contents();
    if(preg_match('~Fatal error~', $p))
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
});

...your code...
```

Comment: I edited you register_shutdown_function-method, that's actually how I did it now (except I don't send a header but print some json indicating the error (see Tomalak Geret'kal's answer for the reason why)). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm, my changes are gone. I'll never understand stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

> With AJAX-requests on the other hand
>   you cannot be sure if you get an error
>   or the data you want because it isn't
>   displayed directly — you just run into
>   troubles because your app won't work
>   anymore.

Yes, you can.

Your XHR `success` callback fires when the transfer of data was successful. Given an application-layer logical error, that data might be some error message. Your `success` callback can and should parse the data it gets from the server, and determine whether there was an error.

> So I thought about an
>   error-handling-system. My best idea is
>   to send a 500 "Internal Server Error"
>   header if an error occurs, so in my
>   JS, when I send an AJAX-Request, I can
>   simply check for errors that way and
>   handle it.

An "Internal Server Error" is generated when there's an error internal to your web server. You do not have an error internal to your webserver; you have a logical error within your application. Thus manually invoking such a status code is inappropriate.

> Unfortunately PHP doesn't send that
>   kind of header (like when you have a
>   parse-error, or something in your code
>   goes wrong) natively.

For the good reason above. There are *different* kinds of errors, and a PHP/application error does not prevent the webserver from doing its job. The HTTP request still succeeds (it just might not contain the information you were hoping for).

Think about a login form. When you try to login to Facebook but accidentally put in the wrong password, do you get a 500 Internal Server Error? No. You get a webpage, delivered properly with a 200 OK status code, whose text says somewhere "oops, you got your password wrong".

The above all said, I'll now answer your question.

> a) Tell PHP to send headers like 500
>   if an error occurs? Or b) Use
>   set_error_handler to send a 500-header
>   and then call PHP regular
>   errorhandling? Or c) Can you, in any
>   other way sen error-headers when a PHP
>   error occurs?

In all the above cases, whenever you want to send a status header, yes you can do this using the library [header](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```

You could write this in the error handler, or wherever you like.

What you can't do is control what happens when a PHP parse error occurs. Your application is going to have to assume that you have tested all your PHP scripts and that they parse; this doesn't seem like a difficult thing to guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for the part on 5xx errors. I think i'll just send a completely custom header-message. Still I'm wondering if there a convenient way to automatically send headers whenever a PHP error occurs except for taking care of the entire error-handling.

Comment: @Lukas: Yes, use an error handler as I said. And be careful not to send non-standard HTTP headers; stick to the proper meaning of HTTP headers.

Comment: Hmm, is there any header appropriate for errors within the application? Doesn't rails send a 500 in such cases?

Comment: @Lukas: No, there is no such appropriate header. HTTP errors describe application _execution_ failures, not errors that occur _within_ the execution of your application. If Rails does what you say, I disagree with their decision.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot accept 2 answers as correct and stereofrog's reply answered the original question. But thanks, I'm just returning json indicating the error instead of a header now!

Comment: @Lukas: I'm not here to collect "accepted answers"; if stereofrog's reply solved your problem, then indeed mark it as accepted! And, yes, you'd usually write an "error" field in your JSON object. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @Tomalak, i have to disagree with your point. HTTP protocol sees no difference between "web server" and "web application". The 500 error basically says it went something wrong on the server side and this is exactly the case when your application behaves wrong. Sending code 200 along with an error message violates good REST principles in my view.

Comment: @stereofrog: It might make sense for parse errors. But application-level errors are *not* "internal server errors".

Answer (score 2):

Use the `header()` function.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: The problem's not sending a header. The Problem is how to send a header when an error occurs while, at best, keeping PHP's regular error-handling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to set the return different headers.

Really, you should only use 5xx errors for unrecoverable server errors - so in set_error_handler you could check the level of the error and return 500 if needed.

For errors you can handle, you could consider the range of available [4xx](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status codes, or include an array of error information in the returned JSON

Comment: `s/on the server side/on the client side/`?

Comment: When I said errors you can handle on the server side, I was talking about the fact it sounds like he has a error in his application - which you did a good job at pointing out. But yeah, I guess the same could be said of the client side. I'll just change it to be more inclusive :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/set_exception_handler), you can run your own code whenever an error occurs.

This will not catch PHP startup errors, and no parse errors in any PHP code that is parsed before you set your error handler, but all others should be catcheable.