# What is a good way to return an error from PHP to AJAX (jQuery)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I've been searching for a simple, clean and flexible way to return errors to the browser after a `POST` or `GET` request.

Example AJAX request with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ 
  data : {
    method  : 'example',
    input : 1
  },
  success : function(i){
    if(i != 'succes'){
      alert(i);
    }
 }
});
```

Server side response:

```
switch($_POST['method']){
  case 'example':
    if($_POST['input'] == 1) {
      echo 'succes';
    } else {
      echo 'error';
      // or
      die('error');
    }
  break;
}
```

This just doesn't feel solid enough. Does anyone know a good way to capture an error combined with a message?

Comment: Return an error http status code (Like 400 or [whatever fits better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)), so the jQuery ajax error handler is invoked

Comment: Would like to see more about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Esailija is correct; return HTTP status codes so that jQuery's ajax error handler can receive the error.

Comment: Would like to see some nice example :)

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290253/can-you-tell-php-to-send-headers-like-500-when-an-error-occurs#answer-6290538) ?? @Sem

Comment: Here's a django specific example. But the ideas are all there. 

[link](http://mrcoles.com/blog/decorator-django-ajax-views/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want your AJAX call to be compliant with HTTP standards send the proper status codes [defined in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) using the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in PHP. In the future you can call the same PHP page from other apps without forcing specific error-handling.

If the error is application-specific, then return a json-encoded message as said before.

Comment: Making 2 different types of custom errors seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that. If you want to manage errors according to HTTP status codes (404 = not found, 500 = internal server error) then send the proper header. If you want to handle application errors (e.g. 'input error in your form', 'misspelled search query') then go for json_encoded dictionaries.

Answer (score -3):

Use JSON:

```
$error = array(
    'error' => 'SOME_ERROR_DESCRIPTION',
    'message' => 'You have an error blabla'
);
echo json_encode($error);
```

From your JavaScript you can just use the JSON object to handle the error as you like.

Comment: HTTP status codes exist for a reason. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: That depends on what OP wants to do. You can use the HTTP status, but if you need elaborate error handling, that may not be enough. In the case, it is a good idea to hand back a JSON object.

Comment: This is even worse than my own example.. it ends up making lots and lots of redundant code.